# Node Module Dependency 404 - npm can't find package.json

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I have forked this https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps angular module into a private github repo, and I'm now trying to install and reference the fork.

I've ran the following:

```
npm install my-repo\angular-google-maps
```

and get the following error.

```
Could not install from "my-repo\angular-google-maps" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

However this repo, definitely DOES contain a package json. I'm sitting here looking right at it as it taunts me.

Wondering if this is indeed the right command to run, and how to reference it in my angular project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install my-repo\angular-google-maps
```

is equivalent to

```
"angular-google-maps": "file:my-repo\\angular-google-maps"
```

`dependencies` entry. It installs the package from local `my-repo\angular-google-maps` directory, if it exists and contains `package.json`.

```
npm install my-repo/angular-google-maps
```

is equivalent to

```
"angular-google-maps": "my-repo/angular-google-maps"
```

`dependencies` entry. It installs the package from `https://github.com/my-repo/angular-google-maps` GitHub repository.

Considering that you're trying to install it from GitHub fork, the first choice is likely wrong.